# Spring Security: How to redirect to login page if user is logged in via rememberme cookie but authenticated fully is needed

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, remember-me

I want to use authentication via LDAP and Rememberme. If a user is authenticated via Rememberme, but the page requires full authentication, the user should be redirected to the login page.

This is my configuration so far

```
<security:http access-decision-manager-ref="de.test.security.core_accessDecisionManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <security:form-login login-page='/login.html' authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true" />
    <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/login.html" />
    <security:remember-me services-ref="de.test.security.auth.rememberme_services" key="${de.test.security.auth.rememberme_key}" />
</security:http>
```

the problem is, every access deny leads to a redirect to login.html, but I just want a redirect when authentication fully is needed and the user has just authenticated via Rememberme.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve such behaviour?

Comment: The only page that is viewable with remember me is `index.jsp` everything else is protected. So as soon as you request an css file or javascript or whatever this is protected and will lead to a login page.

Comment: I know. There isnt any other content yet. It is just a early setup to test how I can achieve what I have asked above.

Comment: for starters fix your url pattern `/*` is only single level whereas `/**` is zero to more. You have configured it to redirect to `login.html` for every access-denied error, that is what you explicitly configured. Finally your login-page contains `'` you might want to change that to `"`.

Comment: Thx for the hint. I changed it in my config to `/**`. Configuring every access-denied error to redirect to login.html was the only way I found to redirect a remembered user if authentication fully is needed. Every other and better solution is welcome :)